# Split a Master Spreadsheet into Multiple Sheets in Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the code I got from this helpful YouTube video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5bOFNsdHiPk

```
Sub SplitandFilterSheet()

Dim Splitcode As Range
Sheets("Master").Select
Set Splitcode = Range("SplitCode")

For Each cell In Splitcode
Sheets("Master").Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = cell.Value

With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cell.Value).Range("MasterData")
.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="NOT EQUAL TO" & cell.Value, Operator:=xlFilterValues
.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
End With

ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
Next cell
End Sub
```

PROBLEM:

This almost works for me. It splits the Master Data into multiple tabs. The tabs are named correctly with unique employee ID's. But the content of each tab includes ALL data. It splits the unique column values correctly to 1331 1147 1498, but all three sheets have all three id's (1331, 1147, 14798)...its not deleting the ones I don't need in the tab...why? Please help:)

Comment: Are you filtering on the correct column?

Comment: I'm not sure but are you sure `Criteria1:="NOT EQUAL TO"` is correct syntax? Record a macro.

Comment: I tried two different columns, I did it first on Field:=1 which is unique ID's and then I tried a different column which could also be used. Same give the same result. It splits into different tabs, but all info in the Master goes into each

Comment: The column must be that containing the ID. What is `Range("MasterData")`?

Comment: "MasterData" is the Master spreadsheet where all Employee ID's are in

Comment: You need to step through the code to see what's going on because I can't tell.

Comment: `Criteria1:="NOT EQUAL TO"` means that the cells to be filtered literally contain the text "NOT EQUAL TO"... I'm 100% sure that's *not* what you want (`<>` is what you want if I remember correctly).

Comment: The IDs must be in the 4th column of 'Range("MasterData")`.

Comment: @BigBen - thought it looked off. TsIT - why did you change the code in the video?

Comment: You guys are awesome! I actually didn't change it...somehow in VBA it changed itself when I copy and pasted the code. Now it works!!!